# Not able to parse the JSON data from F1 url

Tags: json, api, swift4, alamofire, swifty-json

I am trying to access JSON data using the following url http://ergast.com/api/f1/1950/driverstandings.json

Now I am able to access the data with the following function.

In other words I am able to show the data in the console.  The issue I am having is parsing the JSON data.

I am using Swifty JSON to parse the data and for some reason I am not able to show the data from the API.
The function below updates the UILabel on the storyboard.

Any help would be appreciated.  Below is the entire code for the problem that I am what to solve.  I want to add that there is year for the url is coming a UIPickerView on another view.
    import UIKit
    import Alamofire
    import SwiftyJSON

```
class StandingViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var yearLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var firstLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var secondLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var thirdLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var fouthLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var fifthLabel: UILabel!


var standing = ""
let standingDataModel = WeatherDataModel()
var currentUrl = ""

let SEASON_URL = "https://ergast.com/api/f1"
//let format = ".json"

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    yearLabel.text = standing
    userEnteredNewYear(standing: standing)


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
//MARK: - Networking
/***************************************************************/

//Write the getStandingData method here:
func getStandingData (url: String) {
    Alamofire.request(url, method: .get).responseJSON {
        response in
        if response.result.isSuccess {
            print("Success we got the data!")
            let standingJSON : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
            print(standingJSON)
            self.updateStandingData(json: standingJSON)
        } else {
            print("Error \(String(describing: response.result.error))")
            self.yearLabel.text = "Connection Issues"
        }

    }

}
//Mark: JSON Parsing

func updateStandingData(json: JSON) {
    if case standingDataModel.season = json["MRData"]["StandingsTable"]["season"].intValue {
    standingDataModel.firstDriver = json["DriverStandings"][0]["Driver"]["driverId"].stringValue
        updateUIWithStandingData()
    } else {
        yearLabel.text = "No data available"
    }
}

//Mark user entered data.
func userEnteredNewYear(standing: String) {
    currentUrl = SEASON_URL + "/" + String(standing) + "/driverstandings.json"
    getStandingData(url: currentUrl)

}
func updateUIWithStandingData() {
    yearLabel.text = "\(standingDataModel.season)"
    firstLabel.text = standingDataModel.firstDriver
}

/*
// MARK: - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend ditching SwiftyJSON. Create real model objects instead and use Swift's built-in Codable:

```
struct F1Data: Codable {
    let mrData: MRData

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case mrData = "MRData"
    }
}

struct MRData: Codable {
    let xmlns: String
    let series: String
    let url: String
    let limit, offset, total: String
    let standingsTable: StandingsTable

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case xmlns, series, url, limit, offset, total
        case standingsTable = "StandingsTable"
    }
}

struct StandingsTable: Codable {
    let season: String
    let standingsLists: [StandingsList]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case season
        case standingsLists = "StandingsLists"
    }
}

struct StandingsList: Codable {
    let season, round: String
    let driverStandings: [DriverStanding]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case season, round
        case driverStandings = "DriverStandings"
    }
}

struct DriverStanding: Codable {
    let position, positionText, points, wins: String
    let driver: Driver
    let constructors: [Constructor]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case position, positionText, points, wins
        case driver = "Driver"
        case constructors = "Constructors"
    }
}

struct Constructor: Codable {
    let constructorId: String
    let url: String
    let name: String
    let nationality: String
}

struct Driver: Codable {
    let driverId: String
    let url: String
    let givenName, familyName, dateOfBirth, nationality: String
}

do {
  let f1Data = try JSONDecoder().decode(F1Data.self, from: jsonData)

  let season = f1Data.mrData.standingsTable.season
  let firstDriver = f1Data.mrData.standingsTable.standingsLists[0].driverStandings[0].driver.driverId
} catch {
  print(error)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Gereon.  Basically, the Year in the URL is dynamic.  It is coming from a previous screen which has a UIPickerView.  So how would this apply?

Comment: As the year does not appear to be used as a key in the JSON, you should be fine by simply changing the URL accordingly. One change I would make is keep the driver's nationalities as pure strings instead of enums so you don't have to worry about too many cases there (updated the answer)

Comment: Sorry, Gereon I am not familiar with Codable or Decodable and therefore hesitant about including your code as it might create more issues.  I have edited my original question with the complete code.

Comment: Read up on them [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable). IMO they're both much better than using a 3rd party dependency like SwiftyJSON that forces you to use stringly typed accesses to your data.